# Go: local import in non-local package

Tags: go

I have the following file structure:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── hello
├── pkg
└── src
    └── jacob.uk.com
        ├── greeting
        │   └── greeting.go
        └── helloworld.go

5 directories, 3 files
```

With the following GOPATH

```
/Users/clarkj84/Desktop/LearningGo
```

Upon executing `/usr/local/go/bin/go install jacob.uk.com` within the `src` folder, I get the error `local import "./greeting" in non-local package`

`helloworld.go`:

```
package main;
import "./greeting"

func main() {

}
```

Answer (score 46):

You can't use local import when specifying a non-local package to `go install`. If you want the local import to work, first change working directory to `src/jacob.uk.com` then execute `go install` (without specifying the package).

Of course having the `helloworld.go` you provided you will get an compile error: `imported and not used`. But once you use something from the imported `greeting` package, it should compile.

But you shouldn't use local imports at all. Instead write:

```
import "jacob.uk.com/greeting"
```

And doing so you will be able to compile/run/install it from anywhere.

Comment: this gives a cannot find package error for me.  go-contacts is main folder, apps in sub folder, in main.go "go-contacts/app"

Comment: @icza I'm not sure what yours URL path even means. I've got package in mypkg/mypkg.go how can I import it in main.go?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If I do so I get undefined: greetings.

Comment: @oopexpert The package name is `greeting` not `greetings`.

Comment: @oopexpert Then post a [mcve] in a new question. I don't know what you have. You have to use go modules nowdays.

Comment: I won't, as it would be a duplicate of this question. Nevertheless: I figured out what was going wrong... I will post an answer here soon...

Comment: There is a time and a place to use local imports and that is prior to publishing to a Git repo when in early development.  Also when working for clients who have yet to create the Git repo you need, so you need to work from a local directory while waiting for them to create the repo.

Answer (score 30):

Typing `go build` does not work with relative import paths; you must type `go build main.go`.

`go install` does not work at all with relative import paths.

It is documented at https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths

See

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/1XqcS8DuaNc/discussion
- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12502
- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3515#issuecomment-66066361

for explanation.

Answer (score 16):

You can add the local packages using replace in go 1.11<=
go to your go.mod and use "replace" keyword, as below, (you do not need to create a github repo, just add the lines like this)

```
module github.com/yourAccount/yourModule

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/cosmtrek/air v1.21.2 // indirect
    github.com/creack/pty v1.1.11 // indirect
    github.com/fatih/color v1.9.0 // indirect
    github.com/imdario/mergo v0.3.11 // indirect
    github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter v1.3.0
    github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.7 // indirect
    github.com/pelletier/go-toml v1.8.0 // indirect
    go.uber.org/zap v1.15.0
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200831180312-196b9ba8737a // indirect
)

replace (
    github.com/yourAccount/yourModule/localFolder =>"./yourModule/localFolder"
    github.com/yourAccount/yourModule/localFolder =>"./yourModule/localFolder"
)
```

Then in your main.go =>

```
import (
    alog "github.com/yourAccount/yourModule/localFolder"
    slog "github.com/yourAccount/yourModule/localFolder"
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was voted down as this exact solution has resolved the issue I was having (my packages aren't merged into the root branch in source control until I've finished development on them).
Can anybody advise if this is a "bad" way of dealing with this scenario?

Comment: the path argument of the replace directive does not require quoting. Tested on go1.16.

Comment: Actually the best way to go to your (go workspace) ->  go/src folder and create the project there. This is just a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

you can bypass this using the vendor feature
change `import "./greeting"` to `import "greeting"`
create the vendor directory `mkdir vendor` and create a symlink `ln -s ../greeting vendor/greeting`

Comment: Nice.  Thanks - encouraged me to read about the vendor directory.  Even though I'll probably switch to a dep tool, doing this manually help me understand.

Answer (score 2):

Name of module has to be a unique string. I think that's why we use a domain name for a module name a lot.

```golang
// go.mod
module very-unique

go 1.17
```

In that module name is very unique, I tried package name I have locally like follows.

```golang
import "very-unique/packagename"
```

And (obviously) I had a file (it was `packagename.go` in my case) with this line on top.

```golang
package packagename
```

But it didn't work! It finally worked when I made a directory named `packagename` and moved the file into that directory.

I personally like this solution than using `replace`. Usually I think we should use `replace` when we try a copy of existing library locally (with a path).

Answer (score 0):

There may several thing going wrong. I will provide following setup.

## Check your GOPATH environment variable

The GOPATH variable defines your workspace. You can easily identify the current value if you type "`go env`".

If you install Go under Windows the GOPATH environment variable is set up automatically during installation process. Nevertheless: It could be that this default path is not your preferred choice. You may safely set this variable to a target directory to your wish.

To change environment variables in Windows look here: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/

## Check Workspace Layout

If you have decided where your workspace should reside and set up the GOPATH environemnt variable you should create three folders within the workspace:

src, pkg, bin

The folder "src" is the on where your source code reside. "pkg" includes external imports. "bin" contains the compiled sources.

## Example Project

Layout within your workspace:

```
<workspace directory>
--> src
    --> oopexpertutil
        --> x.go
    --> y.go
--> pkg
    --> ...
--> bin
    --> ...
```

File "x.go"

```
package oopexpertutil

func checkMe(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

File "y.go"

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "oopexpertutil"
)

func main() {

    var data string = "Hello World!"
    var dataAsBytes = []byte(data)

    fmt.Println(data)

    err := ioutil.WriteFile("hello_world.txt", dataAsBytes, 0644)

    fmt.Println(err)

    oopexpertutil.checkMe(err)

}
```

## Disappointment...

This setup is still not working. You may have tried out all other answers that stick to workspace or package layout or "go modules" subject. The final point to consider to make this work is:

**Change the name of the "checkMe" function of the referenced package to "CheckMe" and update the usage as well...**

Go has some convention identifying ***exported functions*** from ***not exported functions*** of a package ***by a starting capital letter***.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to share code between separate files and not separate packages, here's how to do it:

You don't need to `import`, you just have to put the source files in the same directory and specify the same `package` name at the top of each file, and then you can access all the public (Uppercase) functions and types, by referencing them directly, that is, `SomeFunction()` and not `somepackage.SomeFunction()`