# GO - Local import not working

Tags: docker, go

I'm new with golang and I want to build my first simple web application. Every time I want to build my source, I get an error `locale import "./controllers" in non-local package"`.

Here is my folder structure:

```
goTest
├── Dockerfile
├── controllers
│   └── IndexController.go
└── main.go
```

The `main.go` file:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "./controllers"
)

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", IndexController)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

The `IndexController.go` file:

```
package controllers

import (
  "fmt"
)

func IndexController(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) error {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

My `Dockerfile` file (copied from https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/):

```
FROM golang:1.8

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

RUN go-wrapper download   # "go get -d -v ./..."
RUN go-wrapper install    # "go install -v ./..."

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["app"]
```

The docker and go build command:

`docker build -t my-golang-app .`

And at least the console output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/7 : FROM golang:1.8
 ---> b2063493320d
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /go/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 86d4df9fceaa
Step 3/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 282286e66939
Removing intermediate container fe3c0686729a
Step 4/7 : RUN go-wrapper download   # "go get -d -v ./..."
 ---> Running in f34b5a5ef0de
+ exec go get -v -d
github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter (download)
main.go:7:5: local import "./controllers" in non-local package
The command '/bin/sh -c go-wrapper download   # "go get -d -v ./..."' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885098/go-local-import-in-non-local-package

Use  "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/controllers" instead of "./controllers"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go: local import in non-local package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885098/go-local-import-in-non-local-package)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang Build in docker not finding local import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219800/golang-build-in-docker-not-finding-local-import)

Answer (score 4):

‍♂️

I finally found the issue. In the `main.go` file I have to import `app/controllers` instead of `./controllers` because in the `Dockerfile` the path is `/go/src/app`.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue but I would urge you to follow the advice of nilsmagnus (and all golang documentation) and avoid local imports. Set up your environment as recommended and use a fully qualified import. I promise this will make your life easier later. golinter will moan at you if you use local imports as well