# Golang Build in docker not finding local import

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I am pretty new to GoLang.  I have a pretty simple dockerFile that is trying to build a goLang webservice.

```
FROM golang:alpine

WORKDIR /app/webservice_refArch
ADD . /app/webservice_refArch

RUN apk add git
RUN apk upgrade

RUN cd /app/webservice_refArch/ && go get webservice_refArch/restapi
RUN cd /app/webservice_refArch/cmd/reference-w-s-server && go build -o ../../server
ENTRYPOINT ./goapp
```

When the build runs it cannot find a local import.

```
go get webservice_refArch/restapi
```

The error that I get is:

> package webservice_refArch/restapi: unrecognized import path
>   "webservice_refArch/restapi" (import path does not begin with
>   hostname)

When I run that same command on my local (in the same folder) it runs just fine.  I am sure that I am missing something stupid but any thoughts on why it fails when running from docker would be appreciated.

Comment: Use proper import paths. Don't fight the tools.

Comment: Thank you Flimzy.  

I don't know if I understand the comment.   I certainly don't want to "fight the tools" but I might not understand how/why I am.

The local import is pulling in packages that are in the same github repository.   If I put them in separate github repos then it would require mutliple commits into github before building.   That seems like a bad development experience.

Can you elaborate on your comment please?

Answer (score 3):

What is missing is to put your project under `$GOPATH` and if you have local namespace it should also be under the same namespace `$GOPATH/domain.com/`.

A proper way also to do that is to have a multi-stage builds. The basic principle involved with Multi-stage involves invoking a temporary container which can facilitate the application build, then copying the built assets out of that space into a container image that has the least amount of components required to run the app.

```
# builder
FROM golang:1-alpine AS builder
RUN apk add git ca-certificates --update

ENV SERVICE_NAME my_project
ENV NAMESPACE mydomain #if you don't use namespace space just ignore it and remove it from the following lines
ENV APP /src/${NAMESPACE}/${SERVICE_NAME}/
ENV WORKDIR ${GOPATH}${APP}

WORKDIR $WORKDIR
ADD . $WORKDIR

RUN go build

###############################################################

#image
FROM alpine
RUN apk add ca-certificates --update

ENV SERVICE_NAME webservice_refArch
ENV NAMESPACE my_domain #if you don't use namespace space just ignore it and remove it from the following lines
ENV APP /src/${NAMESPACE}/${SERVICE_NAME}/
ENV GOPATH /go
ENV WORKDIR ${GOPATH}${APP}

COPY --from=builder ${WORKDIR}${SERVICE_NAME} $WORKDIR

CMD ${WORKDIR}${SERVICE_NAME}
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you very much.   I will give this a go.   This seems pretty slick

Answer (score 1):

It isn't surely very nice, but if you have difficulties the first times you could copy only the executable file doing something like this:

```
FROM golang:alpine
RUN apk upgrade
COPY goapp .
CMD ./goapp
```

It is surely better to compile code inner the image, but it isn't necessary. So you could compile locally your code, and then move only the executable, and you won't have anymore problem like that.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I wasn't copying over to my GOROOT location.   As a result, when it was trying to find the local resource it wasn't in the GOROOT spot.

Changing the dockerFile to look like this worked...

```
FROM golang:alpine

WORKDIR /go
ADD . /go/src/webservice_refArch

RUN apk add git
RUN apk upgrade

RUN cd /go/src/webservice_refArch/ && go get ./...
RUN cd /go/src/webservice_refArch/cmd/reference-w-s-server && go build -o ../../server
ENTRYPOINT ./goapp
```