# Locally importing package

Tags: go, package, go-modules

I have a package I want to break out my code with called `foo` and it's in a subdirectory called `utils`. When I try to import it to my main.go it can't find it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Error when running `go build`

Error:
`main.go:7:2: local import "./utils/csrf" in non-local package`

So I have folder structured as:

```
github.com/project
  /utils
    foo.go
  main.go
```

The package is written as so:

```
package foo

import (
  "fmt"
)

func Bar() {
  fmt.Printf("function")
}
```

Go Mod:

```
module github.com/project

go 1.15
```

And I'm trying to import is as so in my `main.go` file.

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/project/utils/foo"
)
```

Comment: You're missing a `go.mod` file. Run the following command inside the project's directory: `go mod init github.com/project`.

Comment: @mkopriva Sorry edited to add this. I do have one setup.

Comment: I'm using vscode and assumed it would add items to the go.mod as needed?

Comment: What is the exact error message? If you're using an IDE try compiling the program without the IDE, i.e. run `go build` in the project's directory, if that works then that means that the IDE is not configured properly or has lame support.

Comment: The code in your question and the error do not match. You state that the imports in your `main.go` file are `"fmt"` and `"github.com/project/utils/foo"`, but the error complains about `"./utils/csrf"`. Either you ran `go build` in the wrong project, or the code in the question is far removed from your actual code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go: local import in non-local package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885098/go-local-import-in-non-local-package)

Answer (score 2):

First, make a folder `utils` somewhere. You don't need to do any
`github.com/project` folder. Just simply make a `utils` folder, and put it somewhere on your hard drive. Then go into that folder, and do `go mod init github.com/project/utils`. Then make `utils/foo.go`:

```
package utils
import "fmt"

func Bar() {
   fmt.Println("function")
}
```

Then make a folder `utils/utils`. Then make a file `utils/utils/main.go`:

```
package main
import "github.com/project/utils"

func main() {
   utils.Bar()
}
```

Then do `go build`. Done.

Comment: So the last thing was the answer. I could have sworn I did go build already for the module. But after that, vscode was able to auto-import it when I used it's method in main.go. :facepalm: Thanks everyone, and Steven especially. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message `main.go:7:2: local import "./utils/csrf" in non-local package` comes from [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17beta1:src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go;l=752-766;drc=0eb38f2b164ec5b0094c5895cfe1b3a40c183d50). Barring an unexpected bug, it would imply that your `main.go` does *not* look like:

```golang
import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/project/utils/foo"
)
```

as you described, but, rather, something more like:

```golang
import (
  "fmt"
  "./utils/foo"
)
```

However, [relative import paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths) cannot be used in `import` statements in module mode. (The actual error message you get in module mode is somewhat confusing due to a bug in the `go` command, for which I've filed https://golang.org/issue/47088.)

In module mode, the module path declared in the `go.mod` file — presumably `module github.com/project` for your example — is a prefix of the import path, and you are intended to use the complete path in `import` statements.

So the solution here is likely:

1. `cd` to the `project` folder.
2. Run `go mod init github.com/project`.
3. Change the `import` statements to use the full path instead of the relative one throughout the project:

   ```
   $ sed -i 's,"\./utils,"github.com/project/utils,' $(find -name *.go)
   ```

That should change your `main.go` to *actually* read:

```golang
import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/project/utils/foo"
)
```

But now there is one more step: Go supports only one package per directory, and the package name declared with the `package` directive in the `.go` source file is (perhaps confusingly!) *not* a suffix of the package import path — it is completely independent.

So in order to make that `import` statement work, you need an extra layer of directory structure:

4. `mkdir utils/foo`
5. `mv utils/foo.go utils/foo/foo.go`

Now you have a single module, `github.com/project`, containing two packages: `github.com/project` with source file `./main.go`, and `github.com/project/utils/foo` with source file `./utils/foo/foo.go`.